# Catalog and tag files from offline sources and show them as a drive

Tags: file-management, file-synchronization

I have 2 or 3 sources where I store my files. My laptop, a flash disk, a portable drive or a network NAS.

What I would like to do, is:

1. to catalog all of them and create a virtual file system and see them as if they are a new drive on my machine. [git-annex](https://git-annex.branchable.com/) has some support to add multiple files, but I don't need the version control, and I cannot use tags, or mount a filesystem.
2. it would also be nice to add multiple tags for some files, and based on this, create a new directory structure, and update the virtual file system to see that. [TSMU](https://github.com/oniony/TMSU) seems to do that, but you need to have the physical file.

Maybe it might be possible to achieve what I want with the 2 programs mentioned above, but I'd like to know if there is a more straight forward way.

So I'm looking for a software to catalog my files and ideally it should mount the catalogs as a virtual file system. It should be a Linux/Mac os solution, up to 100 USD one-time price is OK.